# OCaml polymorphic variants: bind the same name in multiple match patterns

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I'm not sure if the title explains it well, but here's a concrete example: I have a polymorphic variant for shapes, and a `print_round` function which can act on a subset of those variants (the round ones):

```
type round_shape = [
    | `oval of int * int
    | `circle of int
]

type shape = [
    | round_shape
    | `rectangle of int * int
]

let print_round : round_shape -> unit = function
    | `oval (width, height) -> failwith "todo"
    | `circle radius -> failwith "todo"
```

Now, this function compiles:

```
let print_shape : shape -> unit = function
    | `rectangle _ -> failwith "TODO"
    | `oval _ as round -> print_round round
    | `circle _ as round -> print_round round
```

But that seems repetitive - this is the code I *want* to write:

```
let print_shape = function
    | `rectangle -> failwith "TODO"
    | `oval _ as round | `circle _ as round -> print_round round
```

With that code, I get:

> Error: Variable round must occur on both sides of this | pattern

Which I just don't understand. Clearly `round` does appear on both sides. How can I get this to work to bind `round` as a `round_shape` in that last branch, with minimal type casting?

Comment: Your code is parsed as ``| (`oval _ as round | `circle _) as round``, not as  your intension ``| (`oval _ as round) | (`circle _ as round)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for patterns you need is

```
pattern_1 | pattern_2 ... | pattern_n as name
```

The pattern grammar can be found [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/patterns.html). Taking that into account we get

```
let print_shape = function
    | `rectangle -> failwith "TODO"
    | `oval _ | `circle _ as round -> print_round round
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. I hadn't thought anything would have a lower precedence than `|`